# Cross browser compatibility of the CSS scrollbars

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

We're implementing CSS scrollbars on our website, and they're working fine with all browsers apart the older versions of IE (like IE8).
We cannot get IE to process the same CSS/JS rules in order to obtain the same output.
As we've noticed that some websites have managed to make explorer display the custom bars instead of the standards, I would like to know if someone has a pice of code to share that make the CSS bars appear exactly the same way independently from the browser that the client is using.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An example would help.  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: if you know a site where IE works, have you tried to simply take a look at the source-code to see which framework/plugin they're using... and then try out the same one?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such magical piece of code to make website look the same on all browsers. Each problem is css/js is to be treated specially, especially on IE.

If you want to apply css rules to only internet explorer, you could make use of [IE Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I used this one for custom scroll bars and it supports all major browsers, might be you have used these one..!! anyways here is link
http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

Answer (score 0):

Write custom css for IE8 using conditioanal comments

```
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
.ie8 .bar {
    your code...
}
```